# Object oriented code for populating a value object

Tags: java, oop, procedural-programming

This is a low level design question. I am trying to get a grip on Object Oriented programming.

I am writing a Java class with a method that sets values of data members of a value object. These values are computed by my class according to some business logic. Finally my class is supposed to return the value object so populated. What is the most object oriented way of doing this?

One possible approach, where I seem to be headed is, creating compute() methods inside my Java class for each of the data members (of the VO) that I need to set. Each of these compute methods return the required value which I set using the respective setter method of the value object.
However, I think this approach is more procedural than object oriented as I am just calling these compute methods procedurally in a sequence and populating my value object.

**So what design (...design patterns, maybe?) or best practices can I use / look at, so that this code becomes object oriented.**

Representative code (what I have right now):

```
class Adapter {   // this is my Java class
    MyValueObject applyBusinessLogic(Input object)
    {
        MyValueObject vo = new MyValueObject();
        vo.setA(computeA());
        vo.setB(computeB());
        vo.setC(computeC());
        return vo;
    }

    String computeA() { ...some logic... return a;}
    String computeB() { ...some logic... return b;}
    String computeC() { ...some logic... return c;}
}

class MyValueObject {
      String a;
      String b;
      String c;

      public void setA(String a)
      {
           this.a = a;
      }

      public void setB(String b)
      {
           this.b = b;
      }

      public void setC(String c)
      {
           this.c = c;
      }
}
```

Comment: You could take a look at the Builder pattern http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern

Comment: *"What is the most object oriented way of doing this?"* - There is no such thing as *the most object oriented way of doing*. So I wonder why you ask that way.

Comment: @hakre I basically mean what would be a way of making this procedural code, object oriented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO, it really depends on the responsibilities and what the calculation methods do. You should keep in mind the SRP (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) to do you OO design. Also high cohesion and loose coupling principles.

If computeA(), B and C are not related, then your Adapter class should be split. If they are related, then your Adapter class should be named differently to express what it really does. For instance: TaxCalculator.

Then you could create a new class receiving a TaxCalculator and a MyValueObject which does the apply. Or just leave the apply in the calculator (though it would be two responsibilities for one class, which is usually bad). In the latter case, perhaps you could call the class TaxCalculationsSetter or something similar, and make the compute methods private. Et voila, you would satisfy again the SRP. ;-)

Always keep in mind that "what a responsibility" is, is a somewhat subjective thing.

I hope this has clarified something.

Comment: BTW: calling three methods in a row is not procedural, nor OO. It's just that: calling three methods one after the other.

Comment: Some of the data members of my value objects are objects of classes themselves which I also need to compute. I believe trying to split up my Adapter into some helper utilities each may help. Some can only work on creating these sub objects, and I think I can create some which do all the similar tasks. Will try and update with how this works out as soon as possible. Thanks.

Comment: You should also try TDD (if not doing it already)  It makes much easier and natural to resolve this type of design questions.

Answer (score 1):

As was already mentioned by izaera, it depends a lot on the particulars or the problem, which you have not provided. But, there is at least one thing, which looks not right to me:

It seems that the Construction of your value object requires some logic. Now the question is, where should it go? You have done it in Adapter. But, it is not probably right, for the reason that construction of VO belongs to VO not the Adapter. Hence, I would definitely move that logic to VO itself - as part of its construction.

Hence, moving that logic to VO, in my opinion improves the design.

```
...
MyValueObject vo = new MyValueObject(); 
vo.setA(required input);
vo.setB(required input);
vo.setC(required input);

class MyValueObject {
      String a;
      String b;
      String c;

      public void setA(required input)
      {  
          ... some logic
          this.a = result of logic
      }

      public void setB(required input)
      {  
          ... some logic
          this.b = result of logic
      }

      public void setC(Srequired input)
      {
             ... some logic
          this.c = result of logic
      }
}
```

Obviously, the whole thing becomes much better if construction is done with a Constructor, at once, unless you have to use setters, if say, you are using some ORM etc.

Comment: Interesting. But couldn't this imply that the MyValueObject class is now becoming complex - its no longer following SRP? Computations of each of the attributes a, b, c, etc are complex ones, some requiring service calls.

Comment: Still going down the route you suggested, I am thinking if I should extend MyValueObject class and overload the setters/getters in the sub class, where I can do all the complex computations. This way, the sub class is only doing the computations for the attributes and the super class is just being a plain old value object. Finally I can return the all-cooked instance of the sub class, but referred to by a reference of the super class - MyValueObject. How about that?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can provide more input on the particulars of the design, because I don't have enough info. But, moving the logic to a client class does not reduce its complexity anyways. If you think it is to complex, think of ways to decompose it into module. But again, modules should be logically meaningful, not random break down of code.

Answer (score 0):

Looks ok for me. You should not always look for programming patterns to use. Most important is KISS (Keep it stupid and simple)

I wuld consider if the MyValueObject can be made immutable.

```
class Adapter {   // this is my Java class
    MyValueObject applyBusinessLogic(Input object){
        return new MyValueObject(computeA(),computeB(),computeC());
    }

    String computeA() { ...some logic... return a;}
    String computeB() { ...some logic... return b;}
    String computeC() { ...some logic... return c;}
}

class MyValueObject {
    final String a;
    final String b;
    final String c;

    public MyValueObject(String a, String b, String c){
        this.a=a;
        this.b=b;
        this.c=c;
    }

}
```